# Problem with query in Azure with data coming from IOT Hub

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

Trying to get values out in a query from my **IOT Device** inputs.

But I can' get the syntax right.

If I write the following in my query, to get the value from V out

```
SELECT vqts.V
FROM device
```

I get

```
V
null
null
```

If I write the following in my query

```
SELECT gatewaydata
FROM device
```

I get

```
gatewaydata

[{"tag_id":"ra-ftld://driver-ftld/RNA://$Global/EDGE::[CLXEMULATE]N01","model_id":"HELLO.Machine.Mixer","vqts":[{"v":20,"q":192,"t":"2020-11-13T11:25:31.2600000Z"},{"v":60,"q":192,"t":"2020-11-13T11:25:32.7660000Z"}],"mimeType":"x-ra/cip/dint"}]

[{"tag_id":"ra-ftld://driver-ftld/RNA://$Global/EDGE::[CLXEMULATE]N01","model_id":"HELLO.Machine.Mixer","vqts":[{"v":200,"q":192,"t":"2020-11-13T10:59:08.9640000Z"},{"v":400,"q":192,"t":"2020-11-13T10:59:11.9710000Z"}],"mimeType":"x-ra/cip/dint"}]
```

Any suggestion is very welcome

Below is the input JSON preview in Raw

```
[
  {
    "gatewayData": [
      {
        "tag_id": "ra-ftld://driver-ftld/RNA://$Global/EDGE::[CLXEMULATE]N01",
        "model_id": "HELLO.Machine.Mixer",
        "vqts": [
          {
            "v": 20,
            "q": 192,
            "t": "2020-11-13T11:25:31.2600000Z"
          },
          {
            "v": 60,
            "q": 192,
            "t": "2020-11-13T11:25:32.7660000Z"
          }
        ],
        "mimeType": "x-ra/cip/dint"
      }
    ],
    "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2020-11-13T11:50:54.0473698Z",
    "PartitionId": 0,
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2020-11-13T11:25:35.4010000Z",
    "IoTHub": {
      "MessageId": "cgp-iot-0.6824490650630262",
      "CorrelationId": null,
      "ConnectionDeviceId": "RAEdge",
      "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "637408485822041330",
      "EnqueuedTime": "2020-11-13T11:25:35.0000000",
      "StreamId": null
    }
  },
  {
    "gatewayData": [
      {
        "tag_id": "ra-ftld://driver-ftld/RNA://$Global/EDGE::[CLXEMULATE]N01",
        "model_id": "HELLO.Machine.Mixer",
        "vqts": [
          {
            "v": 200,
            "q": 192,
            "t": "2020-11-13T10:59:08.9640000Z"
          },
          {
            "v": 400,
            "q": 192,
            "t": "2020-11-13T10:59:11.9710000Z"
          }
        ],
        "mimeType": "x-ra/cip/dint"
      }
    ],
    "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2020-11-13T11:50:54.0473698Z",
    "PartitionId": 0,
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2020-11-13T10:59:15.7660000Z",
    "IoTHub": {
      "MessageId": "cgp-iot-0.06258020538786835",
      "CorrelationId": null,
      "ConnectionDeviceId": "RAEdge",
      "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "637408485822041330",
      "EnqueuedTime": "2020-11-13T10:59:15.0000000",
      "StreamId": null
    }
  }
]
```

Thansk kgalic, the last solution opened up my eye'e. Again thanks alot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

Gateway data is an array, and it needs to be flattened before you access the specific properties of the specific object in the array. Here is an example of what you could try:

```
with sensorReadings as (Select * from input),
inputValues as (Select sensorReadings, message.ArrayValue as Data from sensorReadings CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(sensorReadings.gatewayData) as message),
unpackedValues as (select message.ArrayValue as VQTS, inputValues.* from inputValues CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(inputValues.Data.vqts) as message)


SELECT unpackedValues.VQTS.v, unpackedValues.VQTS.q, unpackedValues.VQTS.t, 
       Data.model_id, Data.tag_id, sensorReadings.IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId,
       unpackedValues.*, unpackedValues.Data.*
INTO output
FROM unpackedValues
```

I added in the SELECT clause the following statements:

```
unpackedValues.*, unpackedValues.Data.*
```

This is just for you to understand the structure.

I also advise using local test inputs in the Stream Analytics extension for Visual Studio, as it really helps to understand what is happening.

[image]

Comment: Thansk kgalic

Your suggestion gives me the following result.

[{"v":300,"q":192,"t":"2020-11-16T08:37:05.1960000Z"}]
[{"v":600,"q":192,"t":"2020-11-16T08:37:03.1900000Z"}]

But what if i want to get the following, and with out "Quetes"

ConnectionDeviceId tag_id        model_id  v q t
RAEdge   ftld://driver-ftld/RNA://$Global/EDGE::[CLXEMULATE]N01  HELLO.Machine.Mixer 60 192 2020-11-13T11:25:32.7660000Z

Comment: @TinoJørgensen if this answers your question, can you please accept the answer? Also, if it does not, and you have further questions, can you please update your initial question, as you have better formatting options comparing to the comments. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer based on your last question. Please try using Visual Studio and Stream Analytics extension, as it should help you to understand what queries above do, and what you have to potentially change/adjust in order to get the desired output ;)

Comment: Thansk kgalic, the last solution opened up my eye'e. Again thanks alot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thansk kgalic

Your suggestion gives me the following result.

[{"v":300,"q":192,"t":"2020-11-16T08:37:05.1960000Z"}]
[{"v":600,"q":192,"t":"2020-11-16T08:37:03.1900000Z"}]

But what if i want to get the following, and with out "Quates"
Like a Table with, ConnectionDeviceId,tag_id,model_id,v,q,t as columns

ConnectionDeviceId  tag_id                              model_id        v   q   t
RAEdge          ftld://driver-ftld/RNA://$Global/EDGE::[CLXEMULATE]N01      HELLO.Machine.Mixer 60  192 2020-11-13T11:25:32.7660000Z

Comment: What you can do in the future is to edit your existing question, and update your initial question, and post a comment on my answer that I should have a look at it, instead of adding the comments as answers. I believe this is not aligned with the stack overflow rules. Also, I do not get a notification if you post additional questions as answers. I actually clicked by pure coincidence and saw that you added it here :)